# Specifying DNS for docker build

Tags: docker, dns, docker-machine

When using the [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) command, it's possible to specify what the DNS hosts of the container should be by passing `--dns <dns_server_ip>` arguments.

Is there an equivalent for the [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) command? There is nothing about it in the docs, and trying it throws an error.

Comment: @downvote/close: Docker command line is directly related to programming, and thus this question should be allowed. There is a reason the tag exists and has 11k+ questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A friend of mine suggested another solution:

use `ADD` to insert a `/etc/resolv.conf` into the container as the first build instruction. Then the container will use those settings for all future builds.

This has the benefit of being a per-container issue, so I don't need to make the change globally or start up a new VM.

Comment: How did you keep Docker from overwriting your custom resolv.conf? Seems like no matter what I try with the `ADD`, Docker overwrites it with a default file.

Comment: @JeffPiersol I don't recall running into that problem. Are you sure you aren't adding in another layer that has such a file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. All I have is

`FROM apache/nifi:latest
COPY ./resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
ENV http_proxy="..."`

Comment: @JeffPiersol I'm honestly not sure. Might be worth asking another question about. Is it possible `ADD` works while `COPY` doesn't for some reason? That wouldn't make much sense, but it's the only difference I see from what you are doing to what I was doing. Do note also that I did this two years ago, so things may have changed since then as to how to do this.